# GCP BigQuery message "Not found: Connection" when I use a connection in scripting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am using GCP bigquery. I have an external connection "myconnectionid" defined. This connection is of connection type  "Cloud SQL - MySQL" and it works fine for a running fedarated query from bigquery to the cloudsql mysql instance such as below.

```
SELECT * FROM 
EXTERNAL_QUERY("myconnectionid","SELECT CURDATE() from Dual;")
```

However when I attempt to declare a SQL variable and assign the return value from federated query to that variable ( I suppose that amounts to bigquery scripting) I get a message "Not found: Connection myconnectionid".
Please see example of error causing snippet of code below

```
DECLARE MYDATE DATE;
SET MYDATE = (SELECT * FROM 
EXTERNAL_QUERY("myconnectionid","SELECT CURDATE() from Dual;"))
```

This snippet gives me an error **"Not found: Connection myconnectionid at [2:14]"**

Do gcp bigquery external connections need a special handling in scripting ?
Or more simply ; do you know how I could overcome this error ?

I am reading through google documentation on connections https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-connections#federated_query_syntax
and also the google documentation on big-query scripting
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting
No luck yet.

Your help much appreciated

Thanks !!

Comment: Have you tried to enter the full id of the connection (in the format project-id:location-id:instance-id) as in the example in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#syntax)?

Comment: perfectly works for me in both cases - with short connection id and with full id. meantime (this does not related to your current issue but will most likely be the next one) add limit 1 to the end of query - otherwise you will get `scalar subquery producing more than one element` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new database and connection almost two years after I originally encountered this and ran into exact same problem

The only definitive way I could get this to work is to ensure that the BQ database , the external connection and the cloud SQL database are in exact same region.

So take away is => if you plan to use BQ "federated Queries"  then ensure that the BQ database, the external connection and the cloud SQL database are in exact same region!

Answer (score 3):

I feel you may be hitting a bug that your query was not routed to correct region (where you have the connection defined).

The workaround could be:

- In UI: Query Settings -> Additional settings -> Processing location, pick the location/region where you have the connection defined
- Or, in the query, reference an entity from a dataset in the same location as the connection, for instance, add a query like `SELECT dataset_in_that_location.f();`

Comment: Hi Yun Zhang  I tried changing the settings and that did not help. This problem was a result of the BQ database, Connection and Cloud SQL NOT being in same region. It seems like they have to be in Same region